# Passphrase header - Coinbase API

Tags: api, coinbase.com

When trying to access the Coinbase API I am getting a header required: passphrase error.

How do I create a passphrase?

On the GDAX website, it states you create your passphrase when you create an API key, however, I just created a new Coinbase API key and could not see any option to create a passphrase.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same problem. I can assume that you're creating API keys at https://coinbase.com/.

The passphrase is related to updates they made so far and you have to create API keys at https://pro.coinbase.com/